# How does ActiveRecord::Relation class act like Array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, activerecord

How does ActiveRecord::Relation class act like array?

For example,

```
User.all
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "Alex", nickname: "leha", created_at: "2017-05-05 12:36:31", updated_at: "2017-05-05 12:36:31">]>
```

It returns ActiveRecord::Relation which acts like Array.

If I create my own class `MyClass`

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :relation
  def initialize(options)
    @relation = options
  end
end

m = MyClass.new [1,2,3]
=> #<MyClass:0x007ffa3f9ab730 @relation=[1, 2, 3]>
```

The question is how to make class like ActiveRecord::Relation?

Comment: Oh, the question is not about how to use AR, I'm asking how to make subclass like ActiveRecord::Relation, which acts like array.

Comment: What do you mean by "acts like Array"?

Comment: In _AR_ you can use `User.all[0]`. In my case `MyClass.new([1,2,3]).relation[0]`. How to make class where I could use `MyClass.new([1,2,3])[0]`?

Comment: Why you don't delegate the `:[]` method to `relation`? Check out the [`Forwardable` module in ruby stdlib.](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/Forwardable.html)

Comment: @GlebVishnevsky also, just to clarify, you are not subclassing the AR here, but wrap it into your own class instead.

Comment: Although Relations are array-like, the inverse is not so. The reason is that Relations concern themselves with database interaction while regular arrays don't. If the question is how to turn an Array into a Relation, then maybe the best answer is to pass the array of record ids to the model's 'where' method

Comment: Your question is very unclear: in some parts you talk about "like `Array`" in other parts you talk about "like `ActiveRecord::Relation`". Which is it? Also, what *precisely* do you mean by "like"? What behavior do you expect? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Because includes the module `Enumerable`, that enables a class to be sorted. Most of the methods that Arrays implements came from that specific module. So if you want to create a class that acts like an Array you should implement `Enumerable`.

As you see in the following code from Active Record, you can notice when it is included in the class:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L15

References:

1. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html
2. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#class-Array-label-Iterating+over+Arrays